# Laravel import/export. The csv file I am importing does not work

Tags: laravel, csv, pdf, django-import-export

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, 2021-06-03 12:25:18, 2021-06-03 12:25:18))

Comment: `1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: This means that the amount of the password is mandatory in your table, but you do not send a value for it.

Comment: Or you may have mistyped the value of the `name` attribute on the form html.

Answer (score 0):

it's looks like you dont fill the password field, however it's mandatory